# Why does the matrix of 1 forms associated to the Chern connexion is not nul ?

Tags: complex-geometry

I am a bit confused about the following fact ( cf Griffiths and Harris, principles of algebraic geometry):

Let $E$ be a hermitian vector bundle on a complex manifold M.

Let $D$ be a connexion on E such that $D^{0,1}=\overline{\partial}$ and $D$ compatible wth the metric. 
The fact that D is compatible with the metric implies that $D_{ij}$ ( the matrix associated to D in a unitary frame) is skew hermitian. 
But when I do the computations and using the fact that  $D^{0,1}=\overline{\partial}$,  I find that the $D_{ij}$ are necessarily (1,0) forms. and so are nul because the matrix is supposed to be skew-hermitian. 
If someone can tell me where I am making a confusion, it would be great. Thanks by advance.

Comment: I think I found the problem : The compatibilty with the complex structure does not imply the fact that $D_{ij}$ are (1,0) forms. The mistake I made was to considere the frame as an holomorphic one and so I forgot to apply the $\overline{\partial}$ operator to the frame.